# Jquery to edit css font-family values

Tags: jquery, css, tampermonkey, userscripts

I'm trying to write a userscript that removes the values from font-family if they fall in a user defined list like ['arial', 'verdana', 'open sans'].

Original: `font-family: Arial, Verdana, "Segoe UI", sans-serif;`

Modified: `font-family: "Segoe UI", sans-serif;`

Using jquery, is there an efficient method to remove some matching values or do I have to use replace() method with regex on every attribute?

Also, some websites store the font family values in some other variables like `--ff-sans`, `--ff-serif`, etc. So I would want to edit the values of those variables too.

Comment: You can also redefine the property values of `font-family` using jQuery

Comment: What you're asking is querying the entire DOM, every element, one by one, inspect its **window.getComputedStyle(Node)** and parse the entries for font-family etc etc... Why, in the first place, you want to do what you're asking for? Any specific reason? What's your use-case? Any code to show? Any more indepth details about what you're building?

Comment: @Roko I use `@font-face {font-family: 'Arial'; src: local('sans-serif');}` in Firefox usercss to substitute ugly Windows fonts. That doesn't work in Chrome (with stylus). I was trying to get similar result using Tampermonkey. I'm not very familiar with jquery but it seemed like the best way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Use **getComputedStyle** and its `getPropertyValue` Method to get the current style ("font-family") in your case
- Use `querySelectorAll()` to get your desired Elements matching the provided selector (I used `"body *:not(script):not(style)"`)

```js
// Utility functions
const ELS = (sel, EL) => (EL || document).querySelectorAll(sel);
const getStyle = (EL, prop) => getComputedStyle(EL, null).getPropertyValue(prop);
const matchesSome = (str, arr) => arr.some(x => str.toLowerCase().includes(x.toLowerCase()));


// Define your array of desides matches and replacement:
const fontFamilyMatches = ["arial", "verdana", "open sans"];
const fontFamilyReplace = `"Segoe UI", sans-serif`;

// Get all elelemts inside body
const ELS_all = ELS("body *:not(script):not(style)");

// Replace fonts that match one in the fontFamilyMatches Array
// with the one defined in fontFamilyReplace
ELS_all.forEach(EL => {
  const fontFamily = getStyle(EL, "font-family");

  if (matchesSome(fontFamily, fontFamilyMatches)) {
    EL.style.fontFamily = fontFamilyReplace
  }
});
```

```css
h1,
h2 {
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
}

p {
  font-family: Arial, Verdana, "Segoe UI", sans-serif;
}

blockquote {
  font-family: 'Bookman Old Style', serif;
}

span {
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<h1>Lorem ipsum</h1>

<div>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
  <p>
    Consectetur adipisicing elit.<br> In reiciendis delectus saepe hic.
  </p>
</div>

<p>
  <span>tempora tempore recusandae molestiae!</span> atque sint dolor a! Id quae rem consequatur deleniti autem, <span>aliquid consectetur</span> adipisicing elit. Dicta iusto corporis dolor.
</p>

<h2>Dolor sit amet</h2>

<p>
  ullam eius dignissimos sequi ut.
</p>

<blockquote>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
</blockquote>
```